# Why laravel.log file uploading when i commit to server other files

Tags: git, laravel

I have set up GIT on server. When i committing something, Auto-uploading `laravel.log` from local to server. What should I do?

`.gitingore` file

```
vendor/
node_modules/
npm-debug.log

# Laravel 4 specific
bootstrap/compiled.php
app/storage/
storage/

# Laravel 5 & Lumen specific
public/storage
public/hot
/storage/logs/laravel.log
storage/logs/laravel.log
storage/*.key
.env.*.php
.env.php
.env
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
```

[image]

Comment: is it ```.gitingore``` or ```gitignore```?

Comment: try delete laravel.log on local and commit & push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an example will help:

```
git rm --cached storage/logs/laravel.log
git commit -m "deleted laravel.log"
```

After the `commit` then check your git status with `git status` command.If you have see `deleted storage/logs/laravel.log` sentence that is working it.

Comment: i have lost all **files and folders** from my server after `committing` and apply your instruction.  @ysfkaya

Comment: Are you sure only removed `storage/logs/laravel.log` file ? Run `git hist` command if you are sure. And try getting old commit with `git reset --soft <hash> ` command in local. I do not think your files are missing

Comment: everthing was lost which was listed into `.gitignore file`.

Comment: Ok but it will take time

Comment: there is not a file of `laravel.log`

Comment: i have uploaded image.

Comment: Everything's looks good. So you can check list file with `dir` command on your current path.

Comment: when i upload anything to server via `commit ad push`, my local's` laravel.log` file moved to server. why?

Comment: now when i am login page, now i am getting error  `The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.`

Comment: Did you try @emirgh answer ? Is there `.gitignore` file in `storage/logs/` ? Does your server automatically make changes when you push a commit ?

Comment: i have checked in path of server. there is not `laravel.log` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176256/discussion-between-kinnari-prajapati-and-ysfkaya).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.gitignore` file in `storage/logs/` directory with this content:

```
*
!.gitignore
```